# Are the virus counters on Datasucker only for the current turn?

Tags: android-netrunner

When playing Datasucker virus (anarchs), are the virus counters permanent or do you have to clear them at the end of the turn?  Even worst, do you have to clear them at the end of a run?

> **Datasucker:** Whenever you make a successful run on a central server, place 1 virus counter on Datasucker.  Hosted virus counter: Rezzed piece of ice currently being encountered has -1 strength until the end of the encounter.

Comment: It looks like you're confused at how the effect is written, the effect is `(remove a) Hosted virus Counter:...` It would have been better if FFG had worded these effects that way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Hosted virus counter" is the cost of the effect (i.e. all the words that come after the colon).

If you spend a virus counter to reduce ice strength, the counter is obviously gone immediately.  If you choose not to spend a counter, it won't get cleared, either at the end of the run or the end of the turn.

Comment: That makes total sense.  I can't believe I didn't get this right away... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Virus counters remain on the virus they are on until one of three things happen:

1. The runner uses an effect that causes them to spend the counters, in this case, removing a counter to reduce ice strength using Datasucker.
2. The virus is trashed, counters do not stay on the virus when uninstalled.
3. The corp purges virus counters. This is a three click action, taking the entire corp turn usually, but can also be caused by the upgrade [Cyberdex Virus Suite](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/07027) or the operation [Cyberdex Trial](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/04019).